# Can I specify a Store on a Ember js model?

Tags: ember.js

I am trying to use multiple stores in Ember because I have namespaced models on the api side.

Aka

```
App.Gl.Account = DS.Model.extend //Needs to route to /gl/accounts

App.Company = DS.Model.extend //Routes to /companies
```

My first thought was to define a namespace

```
App.Gl = Ember.Namespace.create({});
//and a store
App.Gl.Store = DS.Store.extend({adapter:DS.RESTAdapter({namespace:'gl'})});
App.Store = DS.Store.extend({adapter:DS.RESTAdapter})
```

problem is the model is automatically binded to the App.Store.

Any other suggestions on how to accomplish namespaced models would be helpful. I dont even need them namespaced on the client js side, as long as there is an easy way to specify the namespace for each individual model

Comment: I'm still spinning when it comes to properly use ember-data, but as per [revision 11](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/BREAKING_CHANGES.md#loading-data), I think you should have multiple adapters as oppsed to multiple stores.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You should never have more than one store in an Ember application.

Instead, you can register adapters for specific types:

```
App.Store.registerAdapter('App.Post', DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  // implement adapter; in this case
  url: "/gl"
}));
```

You will probably want to use the `RESTAdapter` as a starting point, unless you have specific needs and are willing to get down and dirty with the (still evolving) adapter API.

Comment: thanks Yehuda, didn't know this existed, I may submit a pull to add this to guides. I went with the route of extending the RESTAdapter to support namespaced models. i.e. App.Gl.Account would route to '/gl/accounts'

Comment: The alternative would have been to use url: "/gi" in your specific adapter. I will update my answer to be clearer about that.

Comment: I'm not sure where I'm supposed to put that line.  If I include it in my application.js I get "Can't call registerAdapter on undefined", implying there is no 'Store' available.   This store is available in my routes via  this.get('store') but not in my application.js.

Answer (score 5):

In newer versions of ember (I'm running 1.5.0-beta.1+canary.13995621, and 1.4 also seems to lack the registerAdapter method) the api has changed a bit, the registerAdapter method is gone.

Now if you would like a non default adpter for a model you can define a `App.<ModelName>Adapter` and that will automatically be used for that model.

So if you have a Post model and you would like to define the namespace for that model, I think that would be:

```
App.PostAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  namespace: 'gl'
})
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no longer a `registerAdapter` method.

For Ember 2:

> Model-specific adapters can be created by putting your adapter class in an app/adapters/ + model-name + .js file of the application.

Source: [DS.Adapter Class](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Adapter.html)